# How to properly deserialize and iterate over an array of JSON objects

Tags: c#, json

In my app, I'm getting some data in a string format, which I'm converting to json:

```
string stringValue = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(message.Value);

var jsonValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(stringValue);
```

The resulting json string looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "LOCATION_ID": 2800,
    "CITY": "Sao Paulo"
  },
  {
    "LOCATION_ID": 1700,
    "CITY": "Seattle"
  },
  {
    "LOCATION_ID": 2300,
    "CITY": "Singapore"
  },
  {
    "LOCATION_ID": 1600,
    "CITY": "South Brunswick"
  },
  {
    "LOCATION_ID": 1500,
    "CITY": "South San Francisco"
  },
  {
    "LOCATION_ID": 1400,
    "CITY": "Southlake"
  },
  {
    "LOCATION_ID": 2600,
    "CITY": "Stretford"
  },
  {
    "LOCATION_ID": 2200,
    "CITY": "Sydney"
  }
]
```

What syntax can I use to iterate over this json array, and print out one json object at a time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What syntax can I use to iterate over this json array, and print out
>   one json object at a time?

Define a model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int LOCATION_ID { get; set; }

    public string CITY { get; set; }
}
```

and then deserialize to this model:

```
var models = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<MyModel>>(stringValue);
```

and now you are free to iterate with standard C# iteration constructs like the `foreach` keyword:

```
foreach (MyModel model in models)
{
    Console.WriteLine(model.LOCATION_ID);
    Console.WriteLine(model.CITY);
}
```

Comment: Debug.WriteLine or Trace.WriteLine is better practice that relying on Conole.WriteLine.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use dynamics as follows.

Note, this method reduces code footprint and is more readable the alternative approaches:

```
var json = @"[
                    {
                    'LOCATION_ID': 2800,
                    'CITY': 'Sao Paulo'
                    },
                    {
                    'LOCATION_ID': 1700,
                    'CITY': 'Seattle'
                    }
            ]";

dynamic parsedArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
foreach (dynamic item in parsedArray)
    Debug.WriteLine($"Location ID: {item.LOCATION_ID} City: {item.CITY}");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Darin Dimitrov** is spot on answer.

Another alternative, if you don't really want strongly model, is using Dictionary and its qualities.

```
var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>[]>(stringValue);
foreach (var obj in jsonObj)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", obj["LOCATION_ID"], obj["CITY"]); 
}
```